# convert pandas data frame column values into comma separated strings

Tags: python, pandas, string

i have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Column1                      Column2

'['jjhjh', 'adads','adsd']',    'dwdwdqw'
'['adads','adsd']',             'dwdwdqw'
'['jjhjh', 'adads','adsd']',    'dwdwdqw'
'['adads','adsd']',             'dwdwdqw'
'['adads','adsd']',             'dwdwdqw'
```

Although the items in Column1 look like lists of items, they are strings. I want to remove the square brackets from this string, remove the quotes and replace all values in that column with the same values but as comma separated strings. My desired output would be:

```
   Column1                   Column2

'jjhjh', 'adads','adsd',    'dwdwdqw'
'adads','adsd',             'dwdwdqw'
'jjhjh', 'adads','adsd',    'dwdwdqw'
'adads','adsd',             'dwdwdqw'
'adads','adsd',             'dwdwdqw'
```

I tried the following function but it does not replace the elements:

```
def string_convert(column_name):
  lista=[]
  for i in column_name:
    i=i.strip("[]")
    i=eval(i)
    lista.append(i)
  for m in lista:
    if m == tuple:
      column_name = m[0] + ',' + m[1]
    else:
      column_name = m
  return df['other']
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop worked for me.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    tmp_val = row['Column1'].replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(',')
    row['Column1'] = tmp_val
```

This loops through each row of the DataFrame and modifies the cell in Column1 by doing a string replace to remove the characters you don't want(square brackets and single quotes).  Then .split(',') creates the list and the last line of code replaces the original value with our newly created list.

Answer (score 1):

According to the new final needs included by the question creator in her [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660256/11462274), like a generating a final list with all values to `column1`, I recommend doing it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1','column2'])
df['column1'] = ["'['jjhjh', 'adads','adsd']'","'['adads','adsd']'","'['jjhjh', 'adads','adsd']'","'['adads','adsd']'","'['adads','adsd']'"]
df['column2'] = ['dwdwdqw','dwdwdqw','dwdwdqw','dwdwdqw','dwdwdqw']

df['column1'] = df['column1'].replace('\[|\'|\"|\]| ', '', regex=True)

df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.split(',')

final_list = [x for xs in df['column1'].tolist() for x in xs]

print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
['jjhjh', 'adads', 'adsd', 'adads', 'adsd', 'jjhjh', 'adads', 'adsd', 'adads', 'adsd', 'adads', 'adsd']
```

But I confess that there is a risk in this method because if the string you want has a space between the words, they will be removed, so in your case I still think you should be careful with the use.

Greetings from Brazil!

Comment: Greetings from Irelandm Brazil! I'll try this solution. I did not save as ('['jjhjh', 'adads','adsd']'). When I used eval(i) in my function the strings that were within the quotes were converted into tuples.

Comment: If it doesn't work, let me know so I can understand what I missed in my review. (if the problem is being the first and last quote, maybe you can use the_string[1:-1] to remove the first and last character of the string before eval)

Comment: actually it doesn't work because when I print the data frame I do not see the desired output. I'm trying something like: def string_to_list(column_name):
  for i in column_name:
    b=eval(i)
    ",". join(b). I need to have each of the rows in this column converted either into a real list of strings or comma separated strings

Comment: @NatáliaResende I've updated the answer with the before and after output of the changes so you can see if anything is missing.

Answer (score 0):

By leveraging `str.replace()`:

```
df.assign(Column1=df['Column1'].str.replace(r"'\[(.*)\]',", r"\1,", regex=True))

                    Column1                 Column2
0  'jjhjh', 'adads','adsd',               'dwdwdqw'
1           'adads','adsd',               'dwdwdqw'
2  'jjhjh', 'adads','adsd',               'dwdwdqw'
3           'adads','adsd',               'dwdwdqw'
4           'adads','adsd',               'dwdwdqw'
```

Comment: This solution did not work in my case

Comment: @NatáliaResende Thanks for the feedback!  I am interested in what went wrong.  My answer - at least on my data - removes the left outer single quote, the left [, the right-most single quote and the right-most ] - while leaving the comma on the right.  Does that match your requirements?  though it does assume that there are no left of right padding blanks.  So I just update my answer to remove that last assumption.  No need for it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for my cases was the code below because I had in each string quotes, double quotes and squared brackets. With this code I could remove everything and after that the For loop I removed the unnecessary spaces and split each row into a list :

```
df['column1']=df['column1'].replace('\[|\'|\"|\]', '', regex=True)

df['column1']=df['column1'].str.split(',')

lista=[]
for s in df['column1']:
  for a in s:
    lista.append(a)

lista1=[b.strip() for b in lista]
```

Comment: I noticed that in your answer, according to the original values of the question, because there is no removal of whitespace in the regex, they generate strings with a whitespace that should not be produced, see: ```['jjhjh', ' adads', 'adsd', 'adads', 'adsd', 'jjhjh', ' adads', 'adsd', 'adads', 'adsd', 'adads', 'adsd']``` → ```' adads'``` (before the first ```a```). Well, I updated my question because I didn't realize that your final need was to generate a list with all the values of column1, now with this information, I believe that the best option is the one I shared.

Comment: But I confess that there is a risk in this method because if the string you want has a space between the words, they will be removed, so in your case I still think you should be careful with the use.

Comment: It is a very very complicated dataset. I am struggling with the pre-processing of some columns since yesterday. To be honest, I did not provide enough information in my question for good and complete responses, but it is difficult to show all the issues that I faced throughout the process...Its a column with 960 rows, so it was difficult to cover all the cases for a good question and a good response

Comment: During this weekend I'll have free time and I'll generate a column with very random values with all kinds of possibilities, I'll take a look at the best approach and if I find anything interesting, I'll update my answer and let you know. It can also be a risk to use this method because if it happens to be a column with personal or company names, you run the risk of getting a ```Michael O'Bryant``` that will be removed the ```'``` and you don't want that.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer, thanks. Is there any way to contact you so I can explain what is going on? Thanks.